# Google Analytics iOS - No tracking ID to enable IDFA collection for App+Web property

Tags: ios, google-analytics, sdk, idfa

For iOS apps, the app must [collect IDFA](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318039) in order to automatically derive the Age, Gender, and Interests properties.

[Google Analytics guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/optional-features)

I have added pod ‘GoogleIDFASupport’ but unable to set the tracker as there is no tracking ID on Google Analytics -> Admin for a App+Web property.

```
    // Assumes a tracker has already been initialized with a property ID, otherwise
    // getDefaultTracker returns nil.
    let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().tracker(withTrackingId: "NO_TRACKING_ID")

    // Enable IDFA collection.
    tracker!.allowIDFACollection = true
```

I just see the property number on the property panel.

Please advise

[Reference](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317486?hl=en&ref_topic=6317484)

Answer (score 0):

Source - Firebase Support -

Please note that Firebase and Google Analytics are two separate platforms. In regards to the GA Mobile SDK, please note that we have now fully sunset the SDK. You can read more about this topic [here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9167112?hl=en).

As for Firebase, for IDFA to be available in iOS, you just need to link in the following libraries:

```
libAdIdAccess.a
AdSupport.framework
```

Other [steps](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/optional-features) mentioned here are for GA Mobile SDK.